# how to get NEWLY created select width with JS

Tags: javascript, php

I am ganging my head against the wall for 3 hours now. I have this code:

```
function showpctask() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("pcactivitytask").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  };

  xmlhttp.open("GET","showpctask.php"+,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

that opens up a php file inside a div (id  = pcactivitytask). That php file builds a 'select'

I also have this function right here:

```
function setpctaskwidth() {
  var maxtaskwidth = 0;
  $("div .pcactivitytask").each(function(){
    c_width = parseInt($(this).width());
    if (c_width > maxtaskwidth) {
      maxtaskwidth = c_width;
    }
  });

  alert (maxtaskwidth);
}
```

that will show me the max width of all elements with the the class of "pcactivitytask". Yes, the select created by the previous script has that class. If I call both these function it will NOT include the width of the NEWLY created select..... I need to run it AGAIN 'manuall'. I need my script to "onclick" BOTH build the NEW select AND include it in finding the max width by the second script. Thank you.

Comment: your script is calling `setpctaskwidth()` too early, the `select.pcactivitytask` ain't loaded at that point. That's why it doesn't include its width, the select ain't there yet

Comment: Your call to the php backend is an async task, so you need to wait for it to finish. There's probably an uncountable number of explanations of how to this as it's basically the main *thing* to trip over. But simply, in your case, after the line `document.getElementById("pcactivitytask").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;` you need to trigger `setpctaskwidth` in a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XMLhttprequest` works asynchronously, meaning it does not happen in order.

that is why you have the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` callback function, that only runs once the request is finished

you do not specify how you call these two functions but I would expect to see the call to `setpctaskwidth()` inside the `onreadystatechange` function like this:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("pcactivitytask").innerHTML =  xmlhttp.responseText;
      setpctaskwidth();
   }
 };
```

be advised that if the response includes images or other external resources (fonts etc) that don't already exist in the page you might get a different size than the actual final size (it will measure the size before the image is loaded)

Comment: Thank you kind sir!!!! THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: LOL - my pleasure :-)